# SpringBoot Junit testing main method

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have below test for my spring boot main method.

The test tries to start the application 2 times which is expected.

First time when it starts the application it uses the Mock object hewever 2nd time it starts the application it calls the actual bean.

I have `ReferenceDataService` having `@PostConstract` method call which makes rest call to some other application which I don't want in my tests.

Another thing is that `MqConfiguration` which tries to connect to IBM queues that also I would like to avoid in my test.

Please note even though I have added `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters...`  in my test class it does not exclude it.

How do I write test for my main method in this case?

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
        "camel.springboot.java-routes-include-pattern=**/NONE*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {MqConfiguration.class, ReferenceDataCache.class})})
public class MainApplicationTest {

    @MockBean
    private MqService mqService;

    @MockBean
    private ReferenceDataService referenceDataService;

    @SpyBean
    private ReferenceDataCache cacheSpy;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getCurrencies()).thenReturn(new HashMap<>());
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getFrequencies()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getDayCountTypes()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getBusinessDayConverntions()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getRateDefinations()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getBusinessCalendar()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getFinancingTypes()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(referenceDataService.getStaffs()).thenReturn(null);
        MainApplication.main(new String[]{});
    }
}
```

> MainApplication.java (The class to be tested)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableCaching
@AutoConfigureBefore(JmsAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MainApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Pls post all your code and not just parts of it. And you say ot should start two times, but you have one test that calls the main method once.

Comment: One is when i call main method from my test and another is because of annotation `@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class`

Comment: One could think of splitting the test. Like for first you could do for application context load and second for your application context test. Alternatively, are you allowed to use PowerMockito to verify static methods?

Comment: Split up unit tests and application tests.

Comment: Can you please point out to some example or can you please give some hint?  I am writing junit for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could split it into two separate testing parts as we should strive to test a single functionality per test (Single Responsibility Principle). You could model your testing like below:

```
 @Test
 public void applicationContextLoadedTest(){
 }

 @Test
 public void applicationStartTest() {
 //you can add your mocks as per your required dependencies and requirements
  MainApplication.main(new String[] {});
 }
```

Alternatively, if you are allowed to use PowerMockito, then the following link gives you a working example for verifying static invocations.[PowerMockito - SpringBoot test](https://github.com/torstenwalter/spring-starter/blob/master/src/test/java/de/torstenwalter/spring/starter/StarterMockTest.java)